# Hide all countries list in a select dropdown and show only Belgium/BE using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have this select dropdown lists of countries and i want to hide/remove other countries and show only dropdown list Belgium/BE. My problem is i want to remove/hide other countries except Belgium/BE. Here is my jquery code below

```
  $( "option" ).each(function( index ) {
                console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );

            });
```

and this is the output in console

```
0: Albanië
main.js (line 10)
1: Algerije
main.js (line 10)
2: Amerika
main.js (line 10)
3: Angola
main.js (line 10)
4: Argentinië
main.js (line 10)
5: Armenië
main.js (line 10)
6: Australië
main.js (line 10)
7: Azarbaijan
main.js (line 10)
8: Bahamas
main.js (line 10)
9: Bahrain
main.js (line 10)
10: Bangladesh
main.js (line 10)
11: België
main.js (line 10)
12: Bolivië
main.js (line 10)
13: Borundi
main.js (line 10)
14: Brazilië
main.js (line 10)
15: Bulgarije
main.js (line 10)
16: Cambodja
main.js (line 10)
17: Canada
main.js (line 10)
18: Chili
main.js (line 10)
19: China
main.js (line 10)
20: Colombia
main.js (line 10)
21: Croatië
main.js (line 10)
22: Cuba
main.js (line 10)
23: Cyprus
main.js (line 10)
24: Denemarken
main.js (line 10)
25: Dominikaanse republiek
main.js (line 10)
26: Duitsland
main.js (line 10)
27: Egypte
main.js (line 10)
28: Equador
main.js (line 10)
29: Estland
main.js (line 10)
30: Filipijnen
main.js (line 10)
31: Finland
main.js (line 10)
32: Frankrijk
main.js (line 10)
33: Georgië
main.js (line 10)
34: Ghana
main.js (line 10)
35: Griekenland
main.js (line 10)
36: Haïti
main.js (line 10)
37: Hongarije
main.js (line 10)
38: Ierland
main.js (line 10)
39: Ijsland
main.js (line 10)
40: Indië
main.js (line 10)
41: Indonesië
main.js (line 10)
42: Irak
main.js (line 10)
43: Iran
main.js (line 10)
44: Israël
main.js (line 10)
45: Italië
main.js (line 10)
46: Ivoorkust
main.js (line 10)
47: Japan
main.js (line 10)
48: Jemen
main.js (line 10)
49: Jorndanië
main.js (line 10)
50: Kameroen
main.js (line 10)
51: Kazakhstan
main.js (line 10)
52: Kirgizstan
main.js (line 10)
53: Kongo
main.js (line 10)
54: Kuwait
main.js (line 10)
55: Laos
main.js (line 10)
56: Letland
main.js (line 10)
57: Libanon
main.js (line 10)
58: Liberië
main.js (line 10)
59: Libië
main.js (line 10)
60: Liechtenstein
main.js (line 10)
61: Litouwen
main.js (line 10)
62: Luxemburg
main.js (line 10)
63: Madagascar
main.js (line 10)
64: Maleisië
main.js (line 10)
65: Malta
main.js (line 10)
66: Marokko
main.js (line 10)
67: Mauritius
main.js (line 10)
68: Mexico
main.js (line 10)
69: Moldavië
main.js (line 10)
70: Monaco
main.js (line 10)
71: Namibië
main.js (line 10)
72: Nederland
main.js (line 10)
73: Nederlandse Antillen
main.js (line 10)
74: Niew Zeeland
main.js (line 10)
75: Niew-Caledonië
main.js (line 10)
76: Nigeria
main.js (line 10)
77: Noord Korea
main.js (line 10)
78: Noorwegen
main.js (line 10)
79: Oekraine
main.js (line 10)
80: Oezbekistan
main.js (line 10)
81: Oman
main.js (line 10)
82: Oostenrijk
main.js (line 10)
83: Pakistan
main.js (line 10)
84: Palestine
main.js (line 10)
85: Panama
main.js (line 10)
86: Paraguay
main.js (line 10)
87: Peru
main.js (line 10)
88: Polen
main.js (line 10)
89: Portugal
main.js (line 10)
90: Qatar
main.js (line 10)
91: Roemenië
main.js (line 10)
92: Rusland
main.js (line 10)
93: Rwanda
main.js (line 10)
94: San Marino
main.js (line 10)
95: Saoedi-Arabië
main.js (line 10)
96: Senegal
main.js (line 10)
97: Servië
main.js (line 10)
98: Slovenië
main.js (line 10)
99: Slowakije
main.js (line 10)
100: Spanje
main.js (line 10)
101: Syrië
main.js (line 10)
102: Tadzikistan
main.js (line 10)
103: Taiwan
main.js (line 10)
104: Togo
main.js (line 10)
105: Tsjechië
main.js (line 10)
106: Tunesië
main.js (line 10)
107: Turkije
main.js (line 10)
108: Turkmenistan
main.js (line 10)
109: United Arab Emirates
main.js (line 10)
110: Uruguay
main.js (line 10)
111: Venezuela
main.js (line 10)
112: Verenigd Koninkrijk
main.js (line 10)
113: Vietnam
main.js (line 10)
114: Wit Rusland
main.js (line 10)
115: Zambia
main.js (line 10)
116: Zimbabwe
main.js (line 10)
117: Zuid Afrika
main.js (line 10)
118: Zuid Korea
main.js (line 10)
119: Zweden
main.js (line 10)
120: Zwitserland
main.js (line 10)
121: Albanië
main.js (line 10)
122: Algerije
main.js (line 10)
123: Amerika
main.js (line 10)
124: Angola
main.js (line 10)
125: Argentinië
main.js (line 10)
126: Armenië
main.js (line 10)
127: Australië
main.js (line 10)
128: Azarbaijan
main.js (line 10)
129: Bahamas
main.js (line 10)
130: Bahrain
main.js (line 10)
131: Bangladesh
main.js (line 10)
132: België
main.js (line 10)
133: Bolivië
main.js (line 10)
134: Borundi
main.js (line 10)
135: Brazilië
main.js (line 10)
136: Bulgarije
main.js (line 10)
137: Cambodja
main.js (line 10)
138: Canada
main.js (line 10)
139: Chili
main.js (line 10)
140: China
main.js (line 10)
141: Colombia
main.js (line 10)
142: Croatië
main.js (line 10)
143: Cuba
main.js (line 10)
144: Cyprus
main.js (line 10)
145: Denemarken
main.js (line 10)
146: Dominikaanse republiek
main.js (line 10)
147: Duitsland
main.js (line 10)
148: Egypte
main.js (line 10)
149: Equador
main.js (line 10)
150: Estland
main.js (line 10)
151: Filipijnen
main.js (line 10)
152: Finland
main.js (line 10)
153: Frankrijk
main.js (line 10)
154: Georgië
main.js (line 10)
155: Ghana
main.js (line 10)
156: Griekenland
main.js (line 10)
157: Haïti
main.js (line 10)
158: Hongarije
main.js (line 10)
159: Ierland
main.js (line 10)
160: Ijsland
main.js (line 10)
161: Indië
main.js (line 10)
162: Indonesië
main.js (line 10)
163: Irak
main.js (line 10)
164: Iran
main.js (line 10)
165: Israël
main.js (line 10)
166: Italië
main.js (line 10)
167: Ivoorkust
main.js (line 10)
168: Japan
main.js (line 10)
169: Jemen
main.js (line 10)
170: Jorndanië
main.js (line 10)
171: Kameroen
main.js (line 10)
172: Kazakhstan
main.js (line 10)
173: Kirgizstan
main.js (line 10)
174: Kongo
main.js (line 10)
175: Kuwait
main.js (line 10)
176: Laos
main.js (line 10)
177: Letland
main.js (line 10)
178: Libanon
main.js (line 10)
179: Liberië
main.js (line 10)
180: Libië
main.js (line 10)
181: Liechtenstein
main.js (line 10)
182: Litouwen
main.js (line 10)
183: Luxemburg
main.js (line 10)
184: Madagascar
main.js (line 10)
185: Maleisië
main.js (line 10)
186: Malta
main.js (line 10)
187: Marokko
main.js (line 10)
188: Mauritius
main.js (line 10)
189: Mexico
main.js (line 10)
190: Moldavië
main.js (line 10)
191: Monaco
main.js (line 10)
192: Namibië
main.js (line 10)
193: Nederland
main.js (line 10)
194: Nederlandse Antillen
main.js (line 10)
195: Niew Zeeland
main.js (line 10)
196: Niew-Caledonië
main.js (line 10)
197: Nigeria
main.js (line 10)
198: Noord Korea
main.js (line 10)
199: Noorwegen
main.js (line 10)
200: Oekraine
main.js (line 10)
201: Oezbekistan
main.js (line 10)
202: Oman
main.js (line 10)
203: Oostenrijk
main.js (line 10)
204: Pakistan
main.js (line 10)
205: Palestine
main.js (line 10)
206: Panama
main.js (line 10)
207: Paraguay
main.js (line 10)
208: Peru
main.js (line 10)
209: Polen
main.js (line 10)
210: Portugal
main.js (line 10)
211: Qatar
main.js (line 10)
212: Roemenië
main.js (line 10)
213: Rusland
main.js (line 10)
214: Rwanda
main.js (line 10)
215: San Marino
main.js (line 10)
216: Saoedi-Arabië
main.js (line 10)
217: Senegal
main.js (line 10)
218: Servië
main.js (line 10)
219: Slovenië
main.js (line 10)
220: Slowakije
main.js (line 10)
221: Spanje
main.js (line 10)
222: Syrië
main.js (line 10)
223: Tadzikistan
main.js (line 10)
224: Taiwan
main.js (line 10)
225: Togo
main.js (line 10)
226: Tsjechië
main.js (line 10)
227: Tunesië
main.js (line 10)
228: Turkije
main.js (line 10)
229: Turkmenistan
main.js (line 10)
230: United Arab Emirates
main.js (line 10)
231: Uruguay
main.js (line 10)
232: Venezuela
main.js (line 10)
233: Verenigd Koninkrijk
main.js (line 10)
234: Vietnam
main.js (line 10)
235: Wit Rusland
main.js (line 10)
236: Zambia
main.js (line 10)
237: Zimbabwe
main.js (line 10)
238: Zuid Afrika
main.js (line 10)
239: Zuid Korea
main.js (line 10)
240: Zweden
main.js (line 10)
241: Zwitserland
```

my html code below

```
<select id="billing_countrycode" name="billing[countrycode]">
                            <option value="AL">Albanië</option>
                            <option value="DZ">Algerije</option>
                            <option value="US">Amerika</option>
                            <option value="AO">Angola</option>
                            <option value="AR">Argentinië</option>
                            <option value="AM">Armenië</option>
                            <option value="AU">Australië</option>
                            <option value="AZ">Azarbaijan</option>
                            <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
                            <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
                            <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
                            <option value="BE">België</option>
                            <option value="BO">Bolivië</option>
                            <option value="BI">Borundi</option>
                            <option value="BR">Brazilië</option>
                            <option value="BG">Bulgarije</option>
                            <option value="KH">Cambodja</option>
                            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
                            <option value="CL">Chili</option>
                            <option value="CN">China</option>
                            <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
                            <option value="HR">Croatië</option>
                            <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
                            <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
                            <option value="DK">Denemarken</option>
                            <option value="DO">Dominikaanse republiek</option>
                            <option value="DE">Duitsland</option>
                            <option value="EG">Egypte</option>
                            <option value="EC">Equador</option>
                            <option value="EE">Estland</option>
                            <option value="PH">Filipijnen</option>
                            <option value="FI">Finland</option>
                            <option value="FR">Frankrijk</option>
                            <option value="GE">Georgië</option>
                            <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
                            <option value="EL">Griekenland</option>
                            <option value="HT">Haïti</option>
                            <option value="HU">Hongarije</option>
                            <option value="IE">Ierland</option>
                            <option value="IS">Ijsland</option>
                            <option value="IN">Indië</option>
                            <option value="ID">Indonesië</option>
                            <option value="IQ">Irak</option>
                            <option value="IR">Iran</option>
                            <option value="IL">Israël</option>
                            <option value="IT">Italië</option>
                            <option value="CI">Ivoorkust</option>
                            <option value="JP">Japan</option>
                            <option value="YE">Jemen</option>
                            <option value="JO">Jorndanië</option>
                            <option value="CM">Kameroen</option>
                            <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
                            <option value="KG">Kirgizstan</option>
                            <option value="CG">Kongo</option>
                            <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
                            <option value="LA">Laos</option>
                            <option value="LV">Letland</option>
                            <option value="LB">Libanon</option>
                            <option value="LR">Liberië</option>
                            <option value="LY">Libië</option>
                            <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
                            <option value="LT">Litouwen</option>
                            <option value="LU">Luxemburg</option>
                            <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
                            <option value="MY">Maleisië</option>
                            <option value="MT">Malta</option>
                            <option value="MA">Marokko</option>
                            <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
                            <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
                            <option value="MD">Moldavië</option>
                            <option value="MC">Monaco</option>
                            <option value="NA">Namibië</option>
                            <option value="NL" selected="selected">Nederland</option>
                            <option value="AN">Nederlandse Antillen</option>
                            <option value="NZ">Niew Zeeland</option>
                            <option value="NC">Niew-Caledonië</option>
                            <option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
                            <option value="KP">Noord Korea</option>
                            <option value="NO">Noorwegen</option>
                            <option value="UA">Oekraine</option>
                            <option value="UZ">Oezbekistan</option>
                            <option value="OM">Oman</option>
                            <option value="AT">Oostenrijk</option>
                            <option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
                            <option value="PS">Palestine</option>
                            <option value="PA">Panama</option>
                            <option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
                            <option value="PE">Peru</option>
                            <option value="PL">Polen</option>
                            <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
                            <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
                            <option value="RO">Roemenië</option>
                            <option value="RU">Rusland</option>
                            <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
                            <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
                            <option value="SA">Saoedi-Arabië</option>
                            <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
                            <option value="RS">Servië</option>
                            <option value="SI">Slovenië</option>
                            <option value="SK">Slowakije</option>
                            <option value="ES">Spanje</option>
                            <option value="SY">Syrië</option>
                            <option value="TJ">Tadzikistan</option>
                            <option value="TW">Taiwan</option>
                            <option value="TG">Togo</option>
                            <option value="CZ">Tsjechië</option>
                            <option value="TN">Tunesië</option>
                            <option value="TR">Turkije</option>
                            <option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
                            <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
                            <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
                            <option value="VE">Venezuela</option>
                            <option value="GB">Verenigd Koninkrijk</option>
                            <option value="VN">Vietnam</option>
                            <option value="BY">Wit Rusland</option>
                            <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
                            <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
                            <option value="ZA">Zuid Afrika</option>
                            <option value="KR">Zuid Korea</option>
                            <option value="SE">Zweden</option>
                            <option value="CH">Zwitserland</option>
                    </select>
```

can someone help me figured this thing out? that only Belgium/BE will display?
Any help is muchly appreciated.TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
$('#billing_countrycode option[value!="BE"]').remove();
```

Comment: It's very useful I have the similar problem. Thanks @bharat-patidar

Answer (score 3):

You can select all the options from the select dropdown except the Belgium one and remove them with one line code.

```
$('#billing_countrycode option[value!="BE"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

well, there is also another way,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#billing_countrycode").find('options').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('value') !== 'BE'){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function hideOptionExcept(value) {
  $('option').hide();
  $('option[value='+value+']).show();
}
```